# append once with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a function where I append an element to another element:

```
$("#frmUrl").addClass("hideUrl").css("margin","0").append('&nbsp;<span class="uico ui-icon-carat-1-w icoSpan"></span>');
```

Naturally, when I call the same function again, another  is appended. How can I rewrite this string to append this span only one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there are 3 things you can do.

One is to create a flag after appending then check

```
var isExist = false;

$("#frmUrl").addClass("hideUrl").css("margin","0").append('&nbsp;<span class="uico ui-icon-carat-1-w icoSpan"></span>');

isExist = true;

if(!isExist){
$("#frmUrl").addClass("hideUrl").css("margin","0").append('&nbsp;<span class="uico ui-icon-carat-1-w icoSpan"></span>');
}
```

And the second one is to check if the DOM already exist on the target DOM

```
var dom =  $("#frmUrl").html();

if(dom.indexOf('&nbsp;<span class="uico ui-icon-carat-1-w icoSpan\"></span>') == -1){
 $("#frmUrl").addClass("hideUrl").css("margin","0").append('&nbsp;<span class="uico ui-icon-carat-1-w icoSpan"></span>');
}
```

And the third one is to check if the element already exist on your target element, by checking its existence on your target

```
var dom = $("#frmUrl").find('.uico').length;

if(dom == 0){
     $("#frmUrl").addClass("hideUrl").css("margin","0").append('&nbsp;<span class="uico ui-icon-carat-1-w icoSpan"></span>');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a condition to it

```
if(! $('#frmUrl').find('span.uico').length > 1){
   $("#frmUrl").addClass("hideUrl").css("margin","0").append('&nbsp;<span class="uico ui-icon-   
    carat-1-w icoSpan"></span>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag variable. Set it to false initially, then prior to executing the append, check the value. If false, proceed with the append and set it to true. Otherwise depending on your code you can use jQuery's `.one()` function to only execute an event once.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#frmUrl:not(:has(.icoSpan))").addClass("hideUrl").css("margin","0").append('&nbsp;<span class="uico ui-icon-carat-1-w icoSpan"></span>');
```